# Reference class constant in xml attribute in android

Tags: android

strings.xml

```
<string name="key_rateHourly">rateHourly</string>
```

layout xml:

```
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/key_rateMileage"
        />
```

**Question:** If we can reference constant from string.xml, which is compiled into a corresponding class R.string, could we do this for our own class with constants? For example:

```
public class Constants {
  final static int MyConstant = 0;
}

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@Constants/MyConstant"
        />
```

??

**The problem is** in tangled way of accessing constant defined in strings.xml:

```
getActivity().getString(R.string.key_rateHourly)
```

while

```
Constants.MyConstant
```

is much shorter and clear.

Comment: There is a big difference which you seem to miss. If you use the string resources then the Android OS will automatically take care of loading the correct string for the current locale or other device settings. Otherwise you have to take care of all of that yourself.

Comment: Why would you use `getActivity().getString(...)` when `Fragment` has its own `getString(...)` method? Also as pointed out above, by using standard resource files, Android will provide localized resources automatically based on locale.

Comment: Ok, I can use getString() of Fragment. What about locales - this is the string value, which is used as KEY of preference setting. And it does't to be in different locales